# Android webview Scrolling behaving weird

Tags: android

In my app I have a webview that the user is allowed to scroll horizontally in, through swipe gestures.

I use an objectanimator to animate the scrolling, but even with a simple scrollTo() the problem still occurs.

Problem: When I just to a certain position using: scrollTo(500, 0); it very often jumps a certain amount of pixels to either side, like a 100px jitter.

If I keep swiping RIGHT after the first swipe is done, the error doesnt occur and it acts as expected, but the moment I stop swiping the last swipe ends with a random jitter.

The code is super simple and basically: myView.scrollTo(X,Y). I am completely stumped as to why this happens. have anyone had similar experiences?

*update* Put the code from the touchevent, some of the outcommented stuff is tedious trial and error.

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(final MotionEvent event) {

    if(swipeable && !animationRunning){
        switch(event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                swipeStartPosition = event.getX();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                // Nothing here, move along.
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

                float swipeDistance = Math.abs(event.getX() - swipeStartPosition);

                // Check if event is click or swipe.
                // A swipe is hardcoded to a distance of 50px.
                if (swipeDistance > 50) {
                    // Swipe.

                    if (event.getX() > swipeStartPosition) {
                        // Right swipe (previous).
                        // Don't swipe if you're on the first page.
                        if (targetPage == 0) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No sections that way, try the other way.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            prevPage = targetPage;
                            targetPage--;

                            //inform main activity about pagechange to update UI
                            mMainActivity.setTargetPage(prevPage, targetPage);

                            /*
                            mWebView.postDelayed( new Runnable () {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mWebView.scrollTo(2560, 0);
                                }
                            }, 3000);
                            */

                            //scrollTo(2560, 0);//targetPage * pageWidth, 0);

                            ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this.mWebView, "scrollX", computeHorizontalScrollOffset(), (targetPage * pageWidth)).setDuration(300);

                            objectAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationStart(Animator arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    animationRunning = false;

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }
                            });
                            objectAnimator.start();

                        }
                    } else {
                        // Left swipe (next).

                        if (computeHorizontalScrollRange() <= (computeHorizontalScrollOffset() + computeHorizontalScrollExtent())) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No sections that way, try the other way.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            prevPage = targetPage;
                            targetPage++;

                            mMainActivity.setTargetPage(prevPage, targetPage);

                            /*
                            mWebView.postDelayed( new Runnable () {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mWebView.scrollTo(5120, 0);
                                }
                            }, 3000);
                            */
                            //scrollTo(5120, 0); //targetPage * pageWidth, 0);

                            ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this.mWebView, "scrollX", computeHorizontalScrollOffset(), (targetPage * pageWidth)).setDuration(300);

                            objectAnimator.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationStart(Animator arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    animationRunning = false;
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator arg0) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                                }
                            });

                            objectAnimator.start();

                        }
                    }

                } else {
                    // Click.
                    // Do nothing here.
                }

//                int pageWidth = getWidth();
//               
//                int targetPage = (int)Math.round(  (pos + event.getX()) / (float)pageWidth  );
//                
//                
//                scrollTo(targetPage * pageWidth, 0);

                break;  
        }
    }

    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Also, the displacement that is happening seems to be bound with the initial touchevent itself rather than the scrolling. If I do the following, and put a 3 sec delay, I see that the displacement happens again a short sec after the touch event, but then when the scrollTo() fires after 3 sec it actually jumps to the correct position:

```
mWebView.postDelayed( new Runnable () {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                mWebView.scrollTo(2560, 0);
                            }
                        }, 3000);
```

It's all very puzzling..

Comment: some codes please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out somewhere in the original code, something messed up.
This is a very different, much simpler example, that works perfectly.

```
float x1,x2;
float y1,y2;

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(event.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            x1 = event.getX();
            y1 = event.getY();
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            x2 = event.getX();
            y2 = event.getY();

            if(x1 < x2){
                //left to right
                prevPage = targetPage;
                targetPage--;

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "left to right", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this.mWebView, "scrollX", computeHorizontalScrollOffset(), (targetPage * pageWidth)).setDuration(300);
                objectAnimator.start();
            }
            if(x1 > x2){
                //right to left

                prevPage = targetPage;
                targetPage++;

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "right to left", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(this.mWebView, "scrollX", computeHorizontalScrollOffset(), (targetPage * pageWidth)).setDuration(300);
                objectAnimator.start();
            }
            /*
            ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(mWebView, "scrollX", computeHorizontalScrollOffset(), (targetPage * displaymetrics.widthPixels)).setDuration(300);
            objectAnimator.start();
            */
            break;

    }

    return true;
}
```